# How to use tikz-timing together with the external library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, tikz-timing

I would like to generate a tikz-timing signal in my LaTeX document and to save it, using external library as pdf file.

Here is an example of a combine code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[
  figure list=true,
  prefix=./]
\usetikztiminglibrary{nicetabs} % a bit strange with \Huge; use belowrulesep to adjust

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
  \begin{tikztimingtable}
   & 4L      \\ 
   & 4H      \\ 
   & 2LCH    \\ 
   & [C]CCCC \\
   & 2{2C}   \\
   \extracode
   \tablegrid[black!25,step=1]
  \end{tikztimingtable}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the error that i get is:

```
Opening 'test.figlist' for writing.
**Writing './signal1' to 'test.figlist'.
)
Runaway argument?
 \par 
! File ended while scanning use of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpi
cture.
<inserted text>
```

Comment: Note that the `border` class option is just for `standalone`. With `scrbook` it is ignored.

Comment: See also: [macros - Problem with environment expansion and the Tikz external library. - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/problem-with-environment-expansion-and-the-tikz-external-library)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `tikztimingtable` is unfortunately not compatible with the `external` library. The `\texttiming` and `\timing` macros will work however. The reason for the incompatibility is because the `tikzpicture` is nested inside `tikztimingtable` which is not supported by `external` as described in section 32.2 *Requirements* of the v2.10 TikZ/PGF manual. 
The error occurs because the `external` library can't find the `\end{tikzpicture}` because it is inside the `\end{tikztimingtable}`.

One workaround to avoid errors is to disable the externalization for `tikztimingtable`s as described in e.g. [tikzexternalize only (or not) for flagged graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14573/2975). You can add a `\tikzexternaldisable` macro inside the `figure` before the `tikztimingtable`.
However, then you will get this benefit only for other `tikzpicture`s. If you only have `tikztimingtable`s you can avoid using `external` altogether.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[
  figure list=true,
  prefix=./]
\usetikztiminglibrary{nicetabs} % a bit strange with \Huge; use belowrulesep to adjust

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
  \tikzexternaldisable
  \begin{tikztimingtable}
   & 4L      \\ 
   & 4H      \\ 
   & 2LCH    \\ 
   & [C]CCCC \\
   & 2{2C}   \\
   \extracode
   \tablegrid[black!25,step=1]
  \end{tikztimingtable}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

An alternative to `external` is the `standalone` class and package. With this you must place the code in question in an file of its own, where you can have a full preamble. This file can then be compiled by itself, i.e. standalone, which is very nice for larger pictures which must be recompiled often during the creation process. With the `standalone` package you can then include the standalone file without removing the preamble. It also allows automatic generation of PDF images from the standalone files. See the manual and search for `mode`.

```
% main document
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary{nicetabs} % a bit strange with \Huge; use belowrulesep to adjust

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
  \includestandalone{sometttable}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

```
% sometttable.tex 
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary{nicetabs} % a bit strange with \Huge; use belowrulesep to adjust

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikztimingtable}
   & 4L      \\ 
   & 4H      \\ 
   & 2LCH    \\ 
   & [C]CCCC \\
   & 2{2C}   \\
   \extracode
   \tablegrid[black!25,step=1]
  \end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```