# externalize only some pictures

Tags: tikz-external

I am using `\tikzexternalize` to compile my pictures outside of the main document.

However, when I issue simple `\tikz` commands within the text, I'd like them to be compiled within the main document, to save some time.

Is there a way to turn externalization on/off, or to just limit it to the `tikzpicture` environment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The global externalization setting can be temporary disabled/enabled (until the end of the TeX group) using `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable`. Another option is to set the `/tikz/external/export={true/false}` key; the variant `/tikz/external/export next={true/false}` applies only for a single picture.

All these are described in the chapter "Externalization Library" of the [TikZ userguide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: Oops! I was using an older version of the manual :)

Comment: Thanks! This answer explains it in a little more detail: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14573/84434 An important notice is that if externalization is disabled using `\tikzset{external/export=false}` then it cannot be turned back on for a single picture using `\tikzset{external/export next=true}`. For beamer I ended up with using `\tikzset{external/only named=true}` and `\tikzsetnextfilename{myfigure}%` on heavy images only.

Answer (score 3):

1. put this at the begin of your preamble

   ```
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \providetoggle{externalize}
    \settoggle{externalize}{true}
   ```
2. put this at the end of your preamble, and most important, after `\makeindex`

   ```
    \newcommand{\notexternal}{%
      \iftoggle{externalize}{\tikzset{external/export next=false}}{}
    }

    \iftoggle{externalize}{\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures-compiled/]}{}
   ```
3. put `\notexternal` before tikz environment/command you don't want to be externalized

In this way:

- you have a short command to disable externalization for a single picture
- you can disable externalization for the whole document by changing `\settoggle{externalize}{true}` to `\settoggle{externalize}{false}`, without having to change anything else

**EDIT: Alternative version**

Externalized pictures are named incrementally, and if you add/remove/swap pictures in your document you have to recompile them all, unless you specify the name for each picture, which can be done with this code:

1. unchanged
2. new code:

   ```
    \newcommand{\externalize}[1][]{%
      \iftoggle{externalize}{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{false}{%
          \tikzset{external/export next=false}%
        }{%
          \ifstrempty{#1}{%
            \ifcurrfiledir{./figures/}{%
              \tikzsetnextfilename{\currfilebase}
            }{}
          }{%
            \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}
          }
        }
      }{}
    }

    \iftoggle{externalize}{\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures-compiled/]}{}
   ```
3. three alternatives:

   - put `\externalize[false]` before tikz environment/command you don't want to be externalized
   - put `\externalize[figure_a]` if you want the external picture to be named `figure_a.pdf`
   - if the picture is included in your document with `\include{./figures/figure_1.tex}`, you can put `\externalize` with no argument if you want the external picture to be named `figure_1.pdf` (if the file is not in the `figures` folder, it will be named incrementally)
   - don't put anything if you want the figure to be externalized and named incrementally

Comment: I believe that 

_you can disable externalization for the whole document by changing \settoggle{externalize}{true} to \settoggle{externalize}{true}, without having to change anything else_

should read

_you can disable externalization for the whole document by changing \settoggle{externalize}{true} to **\settoggle{externalize}{false}**, without having to change anything else_

Comment: @PjancMatuzl you're right, I corrected the answer