# Beamer overlays, tikz external and custom file name

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, tikz-external

This is a follow-up question from [Use tikz external feature with beamer \only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78955/use-tikz-external-feature-with-beamer-only) . Andrew's answer there is excellent, and does the job (almost) perfectly.

The rough edge I have found was when I tried to use `\tikzsetnextfilename` together with it.

Why would I want to do that? Because in beamer, one might need to reorder one's slides, or to add an overlay, etc. In this case, most pictures will need to be regenerated, even if they weren't changed.

What is the problem? The following M(n)WE shows the usual way of using `\tikzsetnextfilename`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  beamer externalizing/.style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \tikzifexternalizing{%
        \ifbeamer@anotherslide
        \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
        \fi
      }{}%
    }%
  },
  external/optimize=false
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{every picture/.style={beamer externalizing}}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \tikzsetnextfilename{figure}
  \only<1>{Image 1:}
  \only<2>{Image 2:}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \only<1>{\node {Overlay 1};}
    \only<2>{\node {Overlay 2};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This doesn't work. I'm not pro enough with latex, beamer and tikz mechanics, but I suspect that the problem is `tikz externalize` trying to generate the two pictures with the same file name.

And indeed, the following code snippet does work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  beamer externalizing/.style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \tikzifexternalizing{%
        \ifbeamer@anotherslide
        \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
        \fi
      }{}%
    }%
  },
  external/optimize=false
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{every picture/.style={beamer externalizing}}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \only<1>{\tikzsetnextfilename{figure-1}}
  \only<2>{\tikzsetnextfilename{figure-2}}
  \only<1>{Image 1:}
  \only<2>{Image 2:}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \only<1>{\node {Overlay 1};}
    \only<2>{\node {Overlay 2};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Now it is still far from perfect. For example, it requires to know precisely how many overlays are needed for every picture.

Hence the question : is there a better, more natural way of achieving this?
If not, is there a way to make this method transparent to the user (so that he doesn't need to count the overlays himself)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can automatically add the overlay number to the file name using the code from [Accessing the current overlay number in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55058/86).  If you only want to do this for some pictures, then use like:

```
  \tikzsetnextfilename{figure-\overlaynumber}
```

To add it to every picture you could make it part of the prefix:

```
\tikzexternalize[prefix=picture-\overlaynumber-]
```

Using the suffix notation, (`\tikzset{external/figure name/.add={}{-\overlaynumber}}`) doesn't seem to work as the `figure name` is overriden by the `\tikzsetnextfilename`.  If you want to automatically add a suffix you'd have to hack `\tikzsetnextfilename`:

```
\let\orig@tikzsetnextfilename=\tikzsetnextfilename
\renewcommand\tikzsetnextfilename[1]{\orig@tikzsetnextfilename{#1-\overlaynumber}}
```

(inside the `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` bit).

Although the most hackish, this one ends up with the nicest file names so it's the one I've gone for.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119428/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\tikzset{
  beamer externalizing/.style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \tikzifexternalizing{%
        \ifbeamer@anotherslide
        \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
        \fi
      }{}%
    }%
  },
  external/optimize=false
}
\let\orig@tikzsetnextfilename=\tikzsetnextfilename
\renewcommand\tikzsetnextfilename[1]{\orig@tikzsetnextfilename{#1-\overlaynumber}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{every picture/.style={beamer externalizing}}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \tikzsetnextfilename{figure}
  \only<1>{Image 1:}
  \only<2>{Image 2:}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \only<1>{\node {Overlay 1};}
    \only<2>{\node {Overlay 2};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Note that it also offers a nice workaround to the "problem" you mentioned in the other question, that you need to regenerate all overlays for a picture in case one is changed (that is with the current CTAN version of `tikz` with the lazy up-to-date check, and assuming you force the regeneration by deleting the appropriate `.pdf`).

Comment: This is very clever. Maybe it should be emphasized that the `\overlaynumber` command is not a native command, but is defined in the link given, to keep things together!

Comment: This is a really good answer, unfortunately there seems to be some incompatibility with `pgfplots` when using `gnuplot contour`. For some reason, it appears that the contours get computed for every single overlay - even for frames that do not even contain them! (Cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522643/119955) Do you have any idea what going on there?

Comment: @Hyperplane I'm afraid I have no experience with `gnuplot contour` so I've no idea what's going on there.  It looks as though you have asked a new question about it, which is the best way to get new ideas.

Answer (score 2):

As an extension to Andrew’s excellent answer, it is possible to co-opt his solution to overcome a major bottleneck of the original approach for using beamer overlays with tikz external. The original solution requires globally disabling the tikz external optimizations (i.e. it sets `external/optimize=false` in the preamble). As a result, during the externalization of any tikzpicture, all other tikzpictures in the document are also typeset, even though they will be discarded in the end. This costs a lot of compilation time for documents with many tikzpictures.

As an alternative, we can use the `\tikzsetnextfilename` macro to locally disable the tikz external optimization only for the to-be-externalized tikzpicture and all preceding ones with the same base name. This will result in a considerable speed-up for presentations with many tikzpictures.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
    \tikzset{
      beamer externalizing/.style={%
        execute at end picture={%
          \tikzifexternalizing{%
            \ifbeamer@anotherslide
            \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
            \fi
          }{}%
        }%
      },
      every picture/.style={beamer externalizing}
    }
    
    % remove the `-\overlaynumber` suffix from the jobname
    % the name is stored in `\job@no@suffix` and the number in `\job@suffix@number`
    \def\strip@suffix#1{%
        \begingroup%
        \edef\@tempa{#1-}%
        \expandafter\endgroup%
        \expandafter\@strip@suffix\@tempa\relax%
    }
    \def\@strip@suffix#1-#2\relax{%
        \ifx\relax#2\relax%
            \edef\job@suffix@number{#1}%
            \def\next{\relax}%
        \else%
            \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\job@no@suffix\relax%
                \def\job@no@suffix{#1}%
            \else%
                \edef\job@no@suffix{\job@no@suffix-#1}%
            \fi%
            \def\next{\@strip@suffix#2\relax}%
        \fi%
        \next%
    }
    % check if the next tikzpicture is the to-be-externalized one
    % or has the same basename and precedes it
    \def\if@is@current@pic#1{%
        \begingroup%
        \def\job@no@suffix{}%
        \strip@suffix\pgfactualjobname%
        \ifnum\job@suffix@number<\overlaynumber\relax%
            \def\job@no@suffix{}%
        \fi%
        \edef\current@pic@basename{#1}%
        \edef\current@pic@basename{%
            \expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\current@pic@basename}%
        }%
        \ifx\job@no@suffix\current@pic@basename%
            \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\@firstoftwo%
        \else%
            \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\@secondoftwo%
        \fi%
    }
    
    % add a `-\overlaynumber` suffix to the next tikzpicture name
    % and disable tikz external optimization where needed
    \let\orig@tikzsetnextfilename=\tikzsetnextfilename
    \renewcommand\tikzsetnextfilename[1]{%
        \orig@tikzsetnextfilename{#1-\overlaynumber}%
        \tikzifexternalizing{
            \if@is@current@pic{\tikzexternal@filenameprefix#1}{%
                \tikzset{external/optimize=false}%
            }{%
                \tikzset{external/optimize=true}%
            }%
        }{}%
    }
\makeatother

\tikzexternalize[only named=true]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{figure}
    \only<1>{Image 1:}
    \only<2>{Image 2:}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \only<1>{\node {Overlay 1};}
        \only<2>{\node {Overlay 2};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a slight optimization to the solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119440 , mainly to avoid generating the same figure multiple times if it is not changed. Unfortunately it is not very automatic and still requires some manual input.

```latex
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{tikznamebeamer@tempcnt}
\def\tikznamebeamer@finalidx{}
\newcommand{\tikznamebeamer}[2][figure]{%
    \def\tikznamebeamer@slidesetidx{%
        \setcounter{tikznamebeamer@tempcnt}{0}%
        \let\tikznamebeamer@finalidx=0%
        \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
            \stepcounter{tikznamebeamer@tempcnt}%
            \let\tikznamebeamer@templist=\relax%
            \forcsvlist{\listadd\tikznamebeamer@templist}{####1}%
            \xifinlist{\number\beamer@slideinframe}{\tikznamebeamer@templist}{%
                \edef\tikznamebeamer@finalidx{\thetikznamebeamer@tempcnt}%
            }{}%
        }%
        \docsvlist{#2}%
    }%
    \tikznamebeamer@slidesetidx%
    \tikzsetnextfilename{#1-\tikznamebeamer@finalidx}%
}
\makeatother
```

The idea is to specify sets of frame where the figure is unchanged. So in a 5-slide frame if we have the following:

```latex
\tikznamebeamer[my-graph]{{2,5},4}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    every node/.style={draw, circle}
}
\node (1) at (0, 0) {1};
\node (2) at (1cm, 0) {2};
\node (3) at (0, 1cm) {3};
\node (4) at (1cm, 1cm) {4};

\draw[visible on=<{2,5}>, ->] (1) to (2);
\draw[->] (1) to (3);
\draw[visible on=<4>,->] (2) to (3);
\draw[->] (3) to (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

`\tikznamebeamer[my-graph]{{2,5},4}` specifies that the custom file name should be prefixed by 'my-graph', and also 3 sets of slides: {1,3}, {2,5}, and {4}. Note that any slides not specified are grouped together, hence {1,3}.

For each set, we use the same file name for the externalization, so that it can be re-used. In this example, 'my-graph-0.pdf' for {1,3}, 'my-graph-1.pdf' for {2,5} and 'my-graph-2.pdf' for {4} will be generated.

The small downside is that you need to manually specify which slides are the same. But I haven't figure out an automatic way of doing this.

This is actually the first piece of serious low level LaTeX code I write in my life, so I really hope someone more knowledgeable could clean it and make it idiomatic.