# Externalizing pgfplots/gnuplots in Beamer -- improving performance of contour plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, tikz-external

I am trying to externalize `pgfplots`, `gnuplot` and `contour gnuplot` in `beamer`. Towards this end I am using the `visible on=<>` facility of `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}` (cf. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/119955) by user [Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3751/daniel)) as well as the [automatic numbering solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119440/119955) from user [Loop Space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/loop-space).

Compiling contour plots can be expensive. I noticed that when compiling `tikz` image with multiple overlays containing `contour gnuplots`, the contour plot gets computed for every single overlay. This is really wasteful since in should only be necessary to compute it a single time, and then include it or not when creating the externalized graphic depending on the visibility status.

Consider the following MWE. When compiling it it can be noticed that **9** sets of contour plots get computed, when only **3** would be necessary. How can this issue be avoided? Obviously the problem gets amplified the more overlays are produced, even if just a few nodes get uncovered. How to fix this problem?

> I suspect a "proper" way to solve this may be to generate intermediate images and than combine them in the following way:

```
for k in num_overlays:
   S_k = collection of all elements visible on overlay k
   T_k = all elements in S_k visible for the first time
   create intermediate image I_k from T_k
   create final image J_k by overlaying I_j for j<=k
   include image J_k on slide k
```

However I have no idea how to implement this algorithm.

(Notice that in contrast to [my other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522643/externalizing-pgfplots-gnuplots-in-beamer-too-many-plots-generated) this one is not about the contours getting computed for the wrong frames, but rather if can avoid that it gets computed multiple times within a single `tikzpicture`.)

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

%% automatic beamer numbering
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119428/86}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\tikzset{
  beamer externalizing/.style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \tikzifexternalizing{%
        \ifbeamer@anotherslide
        \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
        \fi
      }{}%
    }%
  },
  external/optimize=false
}
\let\orig@tikzsetnextfilename=\tikzsetnextfilename
\renewcommand\tikzsetnextfilename[1]{\orig@tikzsetnextfilename{#1-\overlaynumber}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{every picture/.style={beamer externalizing}}
\tikzexternalize[only named=true]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{gnuplot contour}
  \tikzsetnextfilename{contour}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}, domain=-2:2]
    \addplot3[visible on=<1-3>,contour gnuplot={draw color=red,number=20, labels=false}] {x};
    \addplot3[visible on=<2-3>,contour gnuplot={draw color=blue,number=20, labels=false}] {y};
    \addplot3[visible on=<3-3>,contour gnuplot={draw color=black,number=20, labels=false}] {x^2+y^2};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excuse the question, but why do you need to externalize and use `beamer` specifically for this, I have never used `pgfplots` with `gnuplot`.