# Externalizing pgfplots/gnuplots in Beamer -- including "\jobname" in filename

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, tikz-external

I am trying to externalize `pgfplots`, `gnuplot` and `contour gnuplot` in `beamer`. Towards this end I am using the `visible on=<>` facility of `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}` (cf. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/119955) by user [Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3751/daniel)) as well as the [automatic numbering solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119440/119955) from user [Loop Space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/loop-space).

However I noticed a strange behaviour when I try to include `\jobname` in the filename by changing `{#1-\overlaynumber}` to `{\jobname-#1-\overlaynumber}`: when compiling the document the first time I get the following error message:

```
system returned with code 256
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. 
Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
```

and the document is more or less empty. (this is not the case without `\jobname`). When I subsequently compile a the document multiple times it begins to include the images. Only after 4 compilations the document is complete. How to fix this bug?

MWE: (compile with `pdflatex --shell-escape`)

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

%% automatic beamer numbering
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119428/86}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\tikzset{
  beamer externalizing/.style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \tikzifexternalizing{%
        \ifbeamer@anotherslide
        \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
        \fi
      }{}%
    }%
  },
  external/optimize=false
}
\let\orig@tikzsetnextfilename=\tikzsetnextfilename
\renewcommand\tikzsetnextfilename[1]{\orig@tikzsetnextfilename{\jobname-#1-\overlaynumber}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{every picture/.style={beamer externalizing}}
\tikzexternalize[only named=true]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{pgfplots}
  \tikzsetnextfilename{pgfplots}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[visible on=<1-3>] {x};
    \addplot[visible on=<2-3>] {exp(x)};
    \addplot[visible on=<3-3>] {x*x};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{gnuplot}
  \tikzsetnextfilename{gnuplot}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[visible on=<1-3>] gnuplot{x};
    \addplot[visible on=<2-3>] gnuplot{exp(x)};
    \addplot[visible on=<3-3>] gnuplot{x*x};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{gnuplot contour}
  \tikzsetnextfilename{contour}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}, domain=-2:2]
    \addplot3[visible on=<1-3>,contour gnuplot={draw color=red,number=20, labels=false}] {x};
    \addplot3[visible on=<2-3>,contour gnuplot={draw color=blue,number=20, labels=false}] {y};
    \addplot3[visible on=<3-3>,contour gnuplot={draw color=black,number=20, labels=false}] {x^2+y^2};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```